# how use or enable key cache in DSE 6 (key-cache)

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

we are using DSE 6 and after getting very read and write timeout error I found that key cache dose does not enable in this version.how can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Key caching is enabled by default, but to make sure it's on you can check the following:

In your `cassandra.yaml` look for:

```
key_cache_size_in_mb:
```

As long as that value is not zet to zero (0), key caching is enabled on the cluster.  If you change this value, you'll need to bounce the/each node for it to take-effect.

Next, key caching is also controlled on a per-table basis.  When you describe your table, look for the `caching` option:

```
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
```

In the above example, all keys will be cached while row caching is disabled.

Comment: we change a value of `key_cache_size_in_mb` in `cassandra.yaml` and restart node after that run `nodetool info` and see that value of `key_cache_size_in_mb` is changed, However, cache hit rate stays on 0% and no key_cache file create in the saved_cache folder.

Comment: @MohamadrezaRostami Check your logs.  Does Cassandra have write permission to the `saved_caches` directory?  That's where I'd start looking.

Comment: yes, I checked it Cassandra have to write permission to this directory. @Aaron

Comment: And there is no key cache saving operation in my debug.log

Comment: @MohamadrezaRostami Did you find any solution?